# regsvr32 fails in windows docker container

Tags: windows, docker, dll, docker-for-windows, regsvr32

When trying to register a DLL specifically (DAO350.DLL) the regsvr fails with exit code 5.
Command:

> $process = Start-Process "regsvr32" -ArgumentList "/s `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL`"" -PassThru -Wait; $process.ExitCode

Container images that I have tried to run with:

- mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
- mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2020

**I have tried a few things:**

Removing the UAC using the following:

> Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -Value 0
>
> Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorUser -Value 0
>
> Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableLUA -Value 0

Running in isolation using:

> --isolation=hyperv

Running using different account, specifically:

> --user "NT Authority\System"

Taking ownership to ContainerAdministrator of the registry nodes and subnodes, following this account:

https://rnd-solutions.net/2017/05/09/resolve-dao350-dll-registration-issue/

Checking the dependency using dependency walker.

Not sure what I can try more :/ One weird thing, is that I can see that the registry key entry is added once I run the command to:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\4.0

with the correct values, etc. but the process still returns an exit code 5.

When trying to run Add-Type of the said .DLL I have the following errors, so maybe some missing dependencies?

> Add-Type : c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\q1ro04mp\q1ro04mp.0.cs(1) : Unexpected character ''
> c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\q1ro04mp\q1ro04mp.0.cs(1) : >>> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL
> At line:1 char:1

Another approach:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> whoami
nt authority\system

# Install Microsoft Data Access Objects - from here https://archive.org/details/microsoft-data-access-objects-dao-3.5
PS C:\> $process = Start-Process ".\DAO\SETUP.EXE" -Wait -PassThru; $process.ExitCode
0

# Confirm that Dao2535.tlb is present
PS C:\> cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\'; ls
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        12/5/1996  12:00 AM          73184 Dao2535.tlb
-a----        12/2/1996   6:44 PM         582144 dao350.dll
-a----        9/15/2018   9:29 AM         610304 dao360.dll

# Start CMD
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.5329]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

# Run regsvr in the local folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO>start /wait regsvr32 /s dao350.dll

# Error level
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO>echo %errorlevel%
5
```

Using Simon's tool to get the proper error code:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO> C:\RegsvrCli.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\dao350.dll"
RegsvrCli 32-bit - Copyright (C) 2023-2024 Simon Mourier. All rights reserved.

Registering 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\dao350.dll' returned: 0x8002801C (-2147319780)
```

And the meaning of the error code:

```
C:\User> .\Err_6.4.5.exe 0x8002801C
# for hex 0x8002801c / decimal -2147319780
  TYPE_E_REGISTRYACCESS                                          winerror.h
# Error accessing the OLE registry.
# 1 matches found for "0x8002801C"
```

The original error:

```
2024-02-01 21:21:56.444   Spawning 32-bit RegSvr32: "C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "C:\Program
Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL"
2024-02-01 21:21:56.491   Registration failed:
                          RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x5.
2024-02-01 21:21:56.491   Defaulting to Abort for suppressed message box (Abort/Retry/Ignore):
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL

                          Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x5.
```

Comment: The DLL seems to be 32bit. Are you sure you execute the correct 32bit version of `regsvr32.exe`? https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages-a98d960a-7392-e6fe-d90a-3f4e0cb543e5

Comment: yes I have tried with fully qualified name of both System32 and SysWOW64, just in case :) same issue.

Comment: FWIW, 5 is generally "access denied". Why are you doing that by yourself, if the dll is there (or any other DAOxxx.dll in that place latest is DAO36) Windows has already registered it. Otherwise you're supposed to use the (25 years ago) setup package, https://archive.org/details/microsoft-data-access-objects-dao-3.5

Comment: I don't want...but sadly I have a dependency on a commercial tool, and that one during the installation is trying to register it. I don't want to deal with Windows containers at all :D. And yes, generally, it "access denied" but not necessarily, as far as I understand error 5 is returned when DllRegisterServer function fails. But I will give a try to the 25 years old setup package, maybe it works

Comment: same result....

Comment: Regsvr32 here calls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-loadtypelib and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-registertypelib and it probably returns access denied. Have you tried to run `regsvr32 DAO350.DLL`using cmd.exe, from the containing folder itself (not using path). Before that, make sure DAO2535.TLB is aside the DAO350.DLL as well in the same folder. registertype lib writes the key you mentioned but also this one  for the .TLB: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{00025E04-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\3.5

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you so muchf for all the suggestion - just to ensure that you have my entire appreciation! 

I have tried your suggestions, but still getting a 5 - see the update

Comment: Ok the way you get the error with errorcode does not work in the general case. I've made a console tool that can register/unregister a COM object which you can use to make sure what the problem/error is: https://github.com/smourier/RegsvrCli

Comment: hey @SimonMourier here's what I get.

0x8002801C

Which seems to be this: Error accessing the OLE registry.

Comment: just to mention, I have run the tool locally on my machine, with admin rights, and I get the same error code

Comment: Stupid question but why do you think it fails with regsvr32?

Comment: @SimonMourier well, basically, as I said, I am trying to install a software and as part of the installation the setup is trying to register the said DLL, and then it fails, in this specific way - see the last edit.

Also to add, I have tried another DLL (dao360) with your tool, just to check and it returns 0, so it is very much specific to dao350 :/

Comment: Your 5 value from errorcode is wrong. The only way is to run regsvr32 visually without /s

Comment: Well I cannot run without /s since I am in a container...and I cannot replicate the error locally